# Authenticating users without using php nor nodeJs

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, security

**If you don't want to read what im trying to do just skip to the "My question" part :)**

My goal:

developing an application that saves as much server performance as possible.
There is no such thing as 100% secure, the app of course should be as secure as its coded.
However the founder of http://lavabit.com/ actually managed to take his security as far as making it NSA-safe (which obviously is the reason he had to shut it down).

My Progress:

I already discovered the BackboneJS Framework, which has saved me a lot of server-side coding, 
using javascript templating, routing, input validation,client communication using websockets.

My Question:

since installing node or php on the server is a security risk in itself (which is the reason security issues need to be patched on newer versions.).I would like to know if there is a way to authenticate users without being forced to install nodeJs or PHP.

Comment: how about htaccess. to be honest, you appear a bit to paranoid to me. add mod-security and a good ruleset to your php on apache and you'll be save enough! unless you do rocket-sience...^^

Comment: you avoid serverside coding by moving everything to the clientside where users can just arbitrarily rewrite and run the code... this seems secure

Comment: The application is aimed to run offline which requires the templates to run on the client-side.
BackboneJs depends on underscoreJs which is the templating system and jquery.
The is no communication involved with the server yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to use HTTPS then perhaps you could look at just using [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)? The web server itself would do the authentication - [more information on Basic Auth in Apache can be found here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).

I really think the experience you get from using a server-side language and cookies etc. is far richer and offers a much nicer user-experience. I'm not sure I understand the *security risk[s]* which you allude to. Alternatively if security is something which you are hesitant about, and feel that it will slow your app down, then perhaps you should consider designing your programme in such a way that security is not an issue.